# How to scale an element in relation to itself instead of to the parent element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

Currently, I'm trying to make a tooltip of an image in my navbar and I can't figure out how to center it. Essentially, I have a div in mynavbar and I have tooltip that comes out when hovered. I want the tooltip to be positioned such that the center of the tooltip aligns with the center of the image in the div. The problem is I can't use 'left:50%' since it refers to 50% of the parent navbars width which is 100%. This positions the tooltip in the middle of the entire screen instead of the middle of the div. Is there any way I can prevent it from referring to the parent width and instead have it be 50% of its own width? I've added my code here and also in a jsfiddle

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
}

body{
  background-color:rgb(80,155,192);
}

header{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 25% 20% 5% 5% 20% 25%;
    /*                     1   2   3  4   5   6*/
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index:1;
}

header h1{
    grid-column: 1;
    margin-left: 5%;
    padding:10px;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color:rgb(80,155,192);
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: color 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
}
header h1:hover{
    color: black;
}
header h1 a:visited{
    color:rgb(80,155,192);
}

.water-container{
    grid-column: 3;
    background:gray;
}
.water-container:before,
.water-container:after{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -0.25rem;
    left: 50%;
}
.water-container:before{
    content: attr(title);
    color:white;
    padding:0.5rem;
    border-radius: 0.3rem;
    background: #333;
}
.water-icon{
    display: block;
    margin:auto;
    width:3rem;
    transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
    transform-origin: center;
}
.water-icon:hover{
    transform: scale(1.2);
}

.fairy-container{
    grid-column: 4;
}
.fairy-container:hover:after{
    content: attr(data-tooltip);
}
.fairy-icon{
    display: block;
    margin:auto;
    width:3rem;
    transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
    transform-origin: center;
}
.fairy-icon:hover{
    transform: scale(1.2);
}

nav {
    grid-column: 6;
}

.nav_links li{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-inline: 30px;
}

.nav_links li a{
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 15px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    background-color: rgb(80,155,192);
    color: white;
    transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1); 
}
.nav_links li a:hover{
    background-color: rgb(60, 136, 173);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
        <h1><a href="main.html">asdasd</a></h1>

        <div class="water-container" title="water">
            <img src="graphics/water.png" class="water-icon" alt="water icon">
        </div>

        <div class="fairy-container" data-tooltip="fairy">
            <img src="graphics/fairy.png" class="fairy-icon" alt="fairy icon">
        </div>

        <nav>
            <ul class="nav_links">
                <li><a href="">Why?</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

[here is the fiddle code](https://jsfiddle.net/gfv168mh/4/)

Btw Im aware of the other issues in the code, I can fix them.  I'm just confused about this one thing that I dont know how to fix. Thanks!

Comment: It would be easier if your jsfiddle reproduced the bug. Can you fix it?

Comment: Sorry! Let me clarify the problem a bit better. In the fiddle, the tooltip comes out to the right of the 'water icon' div (which I highlighted in gray). I want the tooltip to be centered to this div. The tooltip (which is in dark gray and says 'water')  would have to be a little too the left in order to centered.

Comment: The translate(s) from [CSS transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) is relative to the elements own size

Answer (score 2):

for referring to its parents width, you must use
`position: absolute;`
and to refer to itself,
`position: relative;`